# Find the name, start date and duration in months of projects that have the earliest end date - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I was studying subqueries in sql and couldn't figure out the answer to this question. Following are the tables.

Project(p͟r͟o͟j͟n͟o͟, projname, prestdate, prendate)

```
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+
| projno | projname             | prstdate   | prendate   |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+
| AD3100 | Admin Services       | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 |
| AD3110 | General AD Systems   | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-01 |
| MA2113 | W L Prod Cont Progs  | 2014-02-15 | 2014-12-01 |
| PL2100 | Weld Line Planning   | 2014-01-01 | 2014-09-15 |
```

I came up with this but I think its wrong:

```
select projname
     , prstdate
     , MONTH(prendate - prstdate) as duration 
  from Proj 
 where prendate - prstdate IN (select MIN(prendate - prstdate) from Proj);
```

Comment: Which project has the earliest end date? Or, more precisely, what is the earliest end date?

Comment: @Strawberry just the projects that have the earliest end date. Since English isn't my first language, I am also having trouble understanding this question precisely.

Comment: So what part do you think start date plays in determining end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  But your query is looking at the *duration* of the projects, not the *end date*.

Second, the calculation of the duration is off.  The best function to use is [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

So, just modify the code to look at the end date instead of the duration:

```
select projnamek, prstdate
       timestampdiff(month, prstdate, prendate) as duration 
from Proj 
where prendate = (select min(prendate) from Proj);
```